# IIS Express HTTP 403.14 when Debugging AngularJS SPA with WebAPI2

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've created a solution that contains a Web API 2 project as well as a separate HTML project to house my AngularJS SPA.  The latter project contains index.html with app and Scripts folders.  When I debug locally, I receive HTTP 403.14 Forbidden.  Are there additional configuration steps needed to ensure the app will run locally as well as when deployed to Azure?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 Professional on a Windows Server 2012 VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try browsing directly to the index.html and not only to document root.

If that works, add those line to your web.config to set default document.

```
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>      
            <clear/>
            <add value="index.html"/>
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, I cannot browse to index.html.  Are there other routing directives needed inside web.config?